# Where I can find good examples to run with Digilent Spartan 3E Starter Board?

Tags: fpga

I'm looking for tips that are not on the site of the Digilent.

Comment: glad you asked that question.  I also have that kit.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [opencores.org](http://opencores.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://www.cosmiac.org/spartan3e_tutorials.html

They provide some tutorials. See bellow what can be found there:

[image]